# Shake on Hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a framework Button Hover Effects in jQuery. Please help I want to shake the anchor tag when it is hovered

It looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".neon").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggle().effect("shake")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This can solve the problem.

```js
$("#toggle").hover(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake", {times:2}, 1000  );
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Click anywhere to shake the box.</p>
<div >
  <a href="" id="toggle">Try</a>
</div>
```